# avoid type conversion in Scala

Tags: scala

I have this weird requirement where data comes in as name ->value pair from a service and all the name-> value type is string only (which really they are not but that's how data is stored)

This is a simplified illustration.

```
case class EntityObject(type:String,value:String)

EntityObject("boolean","true")
```

now when getting that EntityObject if type is "boolean" then I have to make sure value is not anything else but boolean so first get type out and check value and cast value to that type. e.g in this case check value is boolean so have to cast string value to boolean to validate. If it was anything else besides boolean then it should fail.

e.g. if data came in as below, casting will fail and it should report back to the caller about this error.

```
EntityObject("boolean","1")
```

Due to this weird requirement it forces type conversion in validation code which doesn't look elegant and against type safe programming. Any elegant way to handle this in scala (may be in a more type safe manner)?

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about casting? Because casting is something you do with `.asInstanceOf[..]` method. It looks more like you're talking about conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is where I'm going to channel an idea taken from a tweet by Miles Sabin in regards to hereogenous mappings (see [this gist on github](https://gist.github.com/milessabin/aae285025a32fac0f5c1).) If you know the type of object mapping names a head of time you can use a nifty little trick which involves dependent types. Hold on, 'cause it's a wild ride:

```
trait AssocConv[K] { type V ; def convert: String => V }

def makeConv[V0](name: String, con: String => V0) = new AssocConv[name.type]{
  V = V0
  val convert = con
}

implicit val boolConv = makeConv("boolean", yourMappingFunc)

def convEntity(name: String, value: String)(implicit conv: AssocConv[name.type]): Try[conv.V] = Try{ conv.convert(value) }
```

I haven't tested this but it "should" work. I've also enclosed it in a Scala `Try` so that it catches exceptions thrown by your conversion function (in case you're doing things like `_.toInt` as the converter.)

Comment: Thanks.This is a super smart trick and will work great. however since this is convEntity will be called like this : def myFunc(entity:Entity,value :String) = convEntity(entity.eType,value) it fails to compile since it has no idea what implicit to use for the passed eType. e.g. this error :  could not find implicit value for parameter conv: 
  AssocConv[entity.eType.type]

Comment: @user2066049 You'll have to know ahead of time what the items could potentially be and then use that to capture it. If you're writing code to feed in any random entity item, then you're right. It requires compile time knowledge. So basically, you have to write your code so that you can force the evaluation into a context where you can match it against those predefined strings.

Comment: I know this post is kind of old but I wondered how to make this useful if `val myValue = "boolean" ; val conv = convEntity(myValue)` does not compile and hard-coding variables is a bad practice? Aren't there a way around to have the above call feasible?

Answer (score 0):

You're really talking about conversion, not casting. Casting would be if the value really were an instance of Boolean at runtime, whereas what you have is a String representation of a Boolean.

If you're already working with a case class, I think a pattern matching expression would work pretty well here.

For example,

```
def convert(entity : EntityObject) : Any = entity match {
  case EntityObject("boolean", "true") => true
  case EntityObject("boolean", "false") => false
  case EntityObject("string", s) => s
  // TODO: add Regex-based matchers for numeric types
}
```

Anything that doesn't match one of the specified patterns would cause a MatchError, or you could put a catchall expression at the end to throw your own exception.

In this particular example, since the function returns Any, the calling coffee would need to do an actual type cast to get the specific type, but at least by that point all validation/conversion would have already been performed. Alternatively, you could just put the code that uses the values directly into the above function and avoid casting. I don't know what your specific needs are, so I can't offer anything more detailed.