# Get a Type from a String

Tags: scala

I am trying to switch my code to a component-oriented design.

My point of contention is the following function `do()` which matches its `s` argument with some priorily known `String`s and calls `compute()` with the adequate type parameter.

```scala
  def do(s: String, summoner: Summoner): String = {
      s match {
        case "a" => summoner.compute[Type_A](outOfScopeVal)
        case "b" => summoner.compute[Type_B](outOfScopeVal)
        case _   => ""
      }
    }
```

I would like to transpose it to a generic `trait` that can be `extended` if any new `Type_x` is required.

---

[EDIT] It would be a library that external developers can enrich at will, adding a new match between a String identifier and a type.

[EDIT2] I call a library defined like the following:

```scala
  trait TypeHolder[T <: Type_top] {def score(...): String}

  object Converters {
    implicit object ConverterOfA extends TypeHolder[Type_A] {
      def convertAndMore(...): String = {
        /*
        compute and return a String
        */
      }
    }
    implicit object ConverterOfB extends TypeHolder[Type_B] {
      def convertAndMore(...): String = {
        /*
        compute and return a String
        */
      }
    }
  }

  case class Summoner(...) {
    def compute[T <: Type_top](...)(implicit summoner: TypeHolder[T]): String = {
        summoner.convertAndMore(...)
    }
  }
```

---

This problem can be reduced to getting a generic tool that returns (some kind of) a `type` based on an input String.

This question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23836385/3896166, nears the expected solution but I can not match the requirement of "know[ing] the type of object mapping names ahead of time" as the input String is received dynamically...

Also, `Shapeless` might be the path to follow, but I merely started going down that path.

Is it even possible?

Comment: Are you receiving this string dynamically?

Comment: Could you expand on your problem a little? Will your users know which type they want when compiling? Or will they receive dynamic strings in runtime? - who will be adding new types? You as the library authors? Or externals?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yes.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I added some precisions in my question next to the [EDIT] banner.

Comment: Can you explain why `compute` uses a type to select the appropriate operation rather than, say, an enumeration? The type does not appear in either the arguments or return type, so it is a little odd to have the function parameterised by type.

Comment: @Tim I edited for more details.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Do you have any idea of a different solution the one Tim proposed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this by converting a `String` to a `type` (if that were possible), but it is not the only way of solving your underlying problem. (This is therefore an [XY question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem))

Instead, you need to build a `Map` that takes you from the `String` to a method that computes the appropriate function. It might work something like this:

```
def computeFn[T <: Type_top] =
  (summoner: Summoner, value: ???) => summoner.compute[T](value)

val computeMap = Map(
  "a" -> computeFn[Type_A],
  "b" -> computeFn[Type_B]
)

def do(s: String, summoner: Summoner): String =
  computeMap(s)(summoner, outOfScopeVal)
```

It should be straightforward to adapt this so that subclasses can add to the `computeMap` object in order to define their own mappings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i accept it. In your first sentence, are you saying it is possible to convert a `String` to a `type`? If it is, I'd be interested in knowing how.

Comment: You might be able to do something with `ClassTag`s from the reflection library, but I'm not familiar with that. I was hoping someone else might give an answer using that technique :)