# Import does not bring implicits in scope

Tags: scala, implicit

I am facing an error about unreachable `implicit`s in scope:

`Error:(38, 68) could not find implicit value for parameter strategy: XXX.NeoStrategy[T]
    (summoner: Summoner, v: String) => summoner.summonEvaluation[T](v)`

I implement the answer of Tim to that question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56668734/3896166

I tried to import the `implicit object` Strategies within `TypeTable` scope with :

```scala
  import XXX.NeoStrategies._
```

but to no success.

The followings are each file of the base logic I want to use:

```scala
  object TypeLib {
    sealed trait Type_top
    trait Type_A extends Type_top
    trait Type_B extends Type_top
  }
```

```scala
  trait NeoStrategy[T <: Type_top] {
    def evaluate(v: String, helper: Helper): Int
  }

  object NeoStrategies {
    implicit object NeoStrategy_A extends NeoStrategy[Type_A] {
      def evaluate(v: String, helper: Helper): Int = 1
    }
    implicit object NeoStrategy_B extends NeoStrategy[Type_B] {
      def evaluate(v: String, helper: Helper): Int = 2
    }
  }
```

```scala
  case class Helper(name: String) {
    def summonEvaluation[T <: Type_top](v: String)(implicit strategy: NeoStrategy[T]): Int = {
      strategy.evaluate(v, this)
    }
  }
```

```scala
  trait TypeOMap {
    protected def computeStuff[T <: Type_top]: (Helper, String) => Int
    protected val computeMap: Map[String, (Helper, String) => Int]
  }
```

```scala
  import XXX.NeoStrategies._

  trait TypeTable extends TypeOMap {
    override protected def computeStuff[T <: Type_top]: (Helper, String) => Int = {
      (helper: Helper, v: String) => helper.summonEvaluation[T](v)
    }
    override protected val computeMap = Map(
      "a" -> computeStuff[Type_A],
      "b" -> computeStuff[Type_B]
    )
  }
```

```scala
class Summoner extends TypeTable {

  def callsMapAndEvaluates(typeIdentifier: String, helper: Helper, param: String): Double = {

    computeMap(typeIdentifier)(helper, param)
  }
}
```

```scala
object StackO {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val mySummoner = new Summoner

    // mySummoner allows the selecting of a given type with
    // its "typeIdentifier" input in combination with the "TypeTable" it extends
    val r = mySummoner.callsMapAndEvaluates("a", Helper("make it right"), "I, parameter")
  }
}
```

This is not the first time I use `implicit`s but not with something like the `computeMap` above. Still, I understand the logic of it, but fail at making it right.

How can I have `summoner.summonEvaluation[T](v)` find the required `implicit`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add context bound

```
override protected def computeStuff[T <: Type_top : NeoStrategy] ...
```

---

It seems you want to work with singleton types. In Scala 2.12 + Shapeless

```
  import shapeless.Witness

  object TypeLib {
    sealed trait Type_top
    trait Type_A extends Type_top
    trait Type_B extends Type_top
  }

  import TypeLib._

  trait NeoStrategy[S <: String] {
    type T <: Type_top
    def evaluate(v: S, summoner: Summoner): Int
  }

  object NeoStrategy {
    type Aux[S <: String, T0 <: Type_top] = NeoStrategy[S] { type T = T0 }
    def mkStrategy[S <: String, T0 <: Type_top](f: (S, Summoner) => Int): Aux[S, T0] = new NeoStrategy[S] {
      override type T = T0
      override def evaluate(v: S, summoner: Summoner): Int = f(v, summoner)
    }

    implicit val NeoStrategy_A: NeoStrategy.Aux[Witness.`"a"`.T, Type_A] = mkStrategy((_, _) => 1)
    implicit val NeoStrategy_B: NeoStrategy.Aux[Witness.`"b"`.T, Type_B] = mkStrategy((_, _) => 2)
  }

  case class Summoner(name: String) {
    def summonEvaluation[S <: String](s: Witness.Aux[S])(implicit
      strategy: NeoStrategy[S]): Int = {
      strategy.evaluate(s.value, this)
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val mySummoner = Summoner("stack question")

    val r = mySummoner.summonEvaluation("a")
    val r1 = mySummoner.summonEvaluation("b")

    println(r) // 1
    println(r1) // 2
  }
```

---

In Scala 2.13

```
  object TypeLib {
    sealed trait Type_top
    trait Type_A extends Type_top
    trait Type_B extends Type_top
  }

  import TypeLib._

  trait NeoStrategy[S <: String with Singleton] {
    type T <: Type_top
    def evaluate(v: S, summoner: Summoner): Int
  }

  object NeoStrategy {
    type Aux[S <: String with Singleton, T0 <: Type_top] = NeoStrategy[S] { type T = T0 }
    def mkStrategy[S <: String with Singleton, T0 <: Type_top](f: (S, Summoner) => Int): Aux[S, T0] = new NeoStrategy[S] {
      override type T = T0
      override def evaluate(v: S, summoner: Summoner): Int = f(v, summoner)
    }

    implicit val NeoStrategy_A: NeoStrategy.Aux["a", Type_A] = mkStrategy((_, _) => 1)
    implicit val NeoStrategy_B: NeoStrategy.Aux["b", Type_B] = mkStrategy((_, _) => 2)
  }

  case class Summoner(name: String) {
    def summonEvaluation[S <: String with Singleton](s: S)(implicit
      value: ValueOf[S],
      strategy: NeoStrategy[S]): Int = {
      strategy.evaluate(s, this)
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val mySummoner = Summoner("stack question")

    val r = mySummoner.summonEvaluation("a")
    val r1 = mySummoner.summonEvaluation("b")

    println(r) // 1
    println(r1) // 2
  }
```

Comment: Could you reproduce the problem? I added as told `: NeoStrategy` both in the `TypeOMap` and the `TypeTable` traits. I get this error: `Error:(X) ambiguous implicit values: both object NeoStrategy_A in object NeoStrategies of type XXX.NeoStrategies.NeoStrategy_A.type
 and object NeoStrategy_B in object NeoStrategies of type XXX.NeoStrategies.NeoStrategy_B.type match expected type XXX.NeoStrategy[T]
    val r = mySummoner.summonEvaluation("a")`. I edited my first post with a few more details.

Comment: @wipman You should specify type parameter: either `mySummoner.summonEvaluation[Type_A]("a")` or `mySummoner.summonEvaluation[Type_B]("a")`.

Comment: The purpose of the setup is to be able to call a `NeoStrategy` by, not specifying a `type`, but just a key (`String`) thanks to the `computeMap` of the `TypeOMap`. That is the point developped in the linked question. Do you have an idea for a workaround?

Comment: @wipman How do you expect type `T` to be inferred in `mySummoner.summonEvaluation[T]("a")`? Both options `mySummoner.summonEvaluation[Type_A]("a")`, `mySummoner.summonEvaluation[Type_B]("a")` are valid.

Comment: @wipman It seems you want to work with singleton types (see update).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I completely wronged you with a bad code base, it was not correct at all and was missing key elements. Does the edited question is clearer?

Comment: @wipman You just need to add context bound `T <: Type_top : NeoStrategy` to `TypeOMap#computeStuff` and `TypeTable#computeStuff`.

Comment: @wipman Anyway all your code with types and implicits etc. is just a hard way to say `Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)`. For your code `mySummoner.callsMapAndEvaluates("c", Helper("make it right"), "I, parameter")` compiles and throws `NoSuchElementException` only at runtime (there's no much sense to bother with types and implicits, which are resolved at compile time). I showed code where `mySummoner.summonEvaluation("c")` doesn't compile (main sense of types and implicits is that).

Comment: @wipman But if you receive the string at runtime my approach will not work. `val a = "a"; mySummoner.summonEvaluation(a)` doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying problem is this:

```
  override protected def computeStuff[T <: Type_top]: (Helper, String) => Int = {
    (helper: Helper, v: String) => helper.summonEvaluation[T](v) // implicit for NeoStrategy[T]...?
  }
```

Since `summonEvaluation[T]` requires an implicit argument of type `NeoStrategy[T]`, this means you must have one in scope for any `T` that's a subclass of `Type_top`. However, `NeoStrategies` only provides two instances: one for `Type_A` and `Type_B`. This is not enough for the compiler. Understandably so - for instance, you haven't provided any `NeoStrategy` for

- `Type_top` itself
- subclasses of `Type_A` and `Type_B` (perfectly legal to create)

There are two basic ways you can handle this:

**Delaying the implicit resolution**

As per the other answer, instead of trying to resolve the implicit inside `computeStuff`, add a context bound there too. If the point where you have to supply the implicit is only reached when you know what `T` is, you won't have to provide instances for any possible subtype.

**Providing implicits for all possible subtypes**

If absolutely you want to keep the implicit resolution inside `computeStuff`, you're going to have to offer a method

```
  implicit def getNeoStrategy[T <: Type_top] : NeoStrategy[T] = ???
```

Unfortunately, doing this is probably going to involve a bunch of reflection and potentially runtime errors for edge cases, so I'd recommend the context bound on `computeStuff`.

Comment: Thanks for providing some more explanations.